# GPIO (using sysfs problem)

Tags: raspbian, gpio, java, troubleshooting

I'm presently trying to use the built-in indicator lights on the Raspberry Pi B+ to provide status:
Green = OK;
Red   = Problem

After turning off the triggers (writing `none` to `/sys/class/leds/led[0,1]/trigger`) I update the LED using the following java code:

```
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(brightnessFile);
    String writeString = isOn?"255":"0";
    fw.write(writeString);
    fw.close();
```

However, I am noticing situations where the program has written 255 to the brightness file (e.g. `/sys/class/leds/led0/brightness` ) but the LED is not illuminated.
Similarly, if I read the value from `/sys/class/leds/led0/brightness`, it doesn't appear to correspond to the current status of the LED.  E.g. the LED is not illuminated, but the value read from `/sys/class/leds/led0/brightness` is 255, etc.

Sometimes after seeing the issue, I might do the following in the shell:

```
sudo bash -c 'echo 255 > /sys/class/leds/led0/brightness'
sudo bash -c 'echo 255 > /sys/class/leds/led1/brightness'
```

which results in `led1` going on, but `led0` remains off (?!)

Alternating values seems to help however:

```
sudo bash -c 'echo 0 > /sys/class/leds/led0/brightness'
sudo bash -c 'echo 255 > /sys/class/leds/led0/brightness'
```

Is this a known bug?  Is there a better way?  - The more I read about pi4j (which also doesn't seem to support the onboard LEDs easily) and wiringPi, it appears that they use sysfs, which (correct me if I am wrong) would seem to be no different from what I am doing here.  In addition to not being reliable, this method seems very slow.

**Speculating to possible causes:**

- SD Card Wear (e.g. if the /sys/ filesystem also maintains a presence on the boot volume)
- Power Supply (seems to be the most common answer to any kind of weird problem)
- Hardware Damage (I will try with another board to see if I get the same thing)

**Strangeness Examples:**

```
pi@pitv:~ $ cat /sys/class/leds/led0/brightness
255
pi@pitv:~ $ sudo bash -c 'echo 0 > /sys/class/leds/led0/brightness'
pi@pitv:~ $ cat /sys/class/leds/led0/brightness
0

(Okay)

pi@pitv:~ $ sudo bash -c 'echo 255 > /sys/class/leds/led0/brightness'
pi@pitv:~ $ cat /sys/class/leds/led0/brightness
0

(Not Okay)

pi@pitv:~ $ sudo bash -c 'echo 255 > /sys/class/leds/led0/brightness'
pi@pitv:~ $ cat /sys/class/leds/led0/brightness
0

(Not Okay)

pi@pitv:~ $ sudo bash -c 'echo 0 > /sys/class/leds/led0/brightness'
pi@pitv:~ $ cat /sys/class/leds/led0/brightness
255

(Not Okay)

pi@pitv:~ $ sudo bash -c 'echo 255 > /sys/class/leds/led0/brightness'
pi@pitv:~ $ cat /sys/class/leds/led0/brightness
255

(Okay)

pi@pitv:~ $ sudo bash -c 'echo 0 > /sys/class/leds/led0/brightness'
pi@pitv:~ $ cat /sys/class/leds/led0/brightness
0

(Okay)

pi@pitv:~ $ sudo bash -c 'echo 255 > /sys/class/leds/led0/brightness'
pi@pitv:~ $ cat /sys/class/leds/led0/brightness
0

(Not Okay)

pi@pitv:~ $ sudo bash -c 'echo 255 > /sys/class/leds/led0/brightness'
pi@pitv:~ $ cat /sys/class/leds/led0/brightness
0

(Not Okay)

pi@pitv:~ $ sudo bash -c 'echo 255 > /sys/class/leds/led0/brightness'
pi@pitv:~ $ cat /sys/class/leds/led0/brightness
0

(Not Okay)

pi@pitv:~ $ sudo bash -c 'echo 0 > /sys/class/leds/led0/brightness'
pi@pitv:~ $ cat /sys/class/leds/led0/brightness
255

(Not Okay)
```

Just to illustrate that there is no other trigger interfering:

```
pi@pitv:~ $ cat /sys/class/leds/led0/trigger
[none] kbd-scrolllock kbd-numlock kbd-capslock kbd-kanalock kbd-shiftlock kbd- altgrlock kbd-ctrllock kbd-altlock kbd-shiftllock kbd-shiftrlock kbd-ctrlllock kbd-ctrlrlock timer oneshot heartbeat backlight gpio cpu0 cpu1 cpu2 cpu3 default-on input panic mmc0 mmc1 rfkill0 rfkill1 
pi@pitv:~ $ cat /sys/class/leds/led1/trigger
[none] kbd-scrolllock kbd-numlock kbd-capslock kbd-kanalock kbd-shiftlock kbd-altgrlock kbd-ctrllock kbd-altlock kbd-shiftllock kbd-shiftrlock kbd-ctrlllock kbd-ctrlrlock timer oneshot heartbeat backlight gpio cpu0 cpu1 cpu2 cpu3 default-on input panic mmc0 mmc1 rfkill0 rfkill1
```

Comment: All the software and hardware modules are perfectly reliable.  If you use them properly they produce the desired results.  That being the case ... ?

Comment: *"this method seems very slow"* -> Why, because you are using syscalls (open, write) with a kernel interface (sysfs)?  How else do you propose to access hardware? ;)  Admittedly, the other approach used on the pi, via `mmap()`ing  hardware registers, is probably faster, but all of this is going to be sub-millisecond stuff either way.  BTW, I believe `wiringPi` uses `mmap()` not sysfs.

Comment: *"if the /sys/ filesystem also maintains a presence on the boot volume"* -> No, it is RAM based.   The linux kernel has a few of these kinds of language agnostic interfaces (`/dev`, `/proc`, `/sys`).

Answer (score 1):

You are wasting your time trying to control the on-board LEDs.

They are controlled by kernel services, and additionally for the Red LED a hardware power monitor.

You CAN change their state, but the kernel will change them independently on its own schedule.

You can modify their behaviour, to a limited extent, by setting up the appropriate configuration in Device Tree.

Comment: I turned off the triggers by writing `none` to `/sys/class/leds/led[0,1]/trigger`... which I think (?) turns off the kernel services attached to the on-board LEDs.